# How get i order total count of specific product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How get i order total count of specific product in woocommerce  i am having the product id on that page but do not getting the order total

Comment: you need pending order's count?

Answer (score 0):

To display the number of units sold for a product add the following snippet of code to your theme’s functions.php file

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_product_sold_count', 11 );
function wc_product_sold_count() {
global $product;
$units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
}
?>
```

This will result in the Units Sold text to display underneath the product title and price.