# How can I add a counter below every product item in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to add a counter below every product item in WordPress website.....to show

**Item order (fetched from order placed) ----out of (fetched from stock no.)**
In simple words, I wanna add a counter that shows **Ordered item out of Stock Item** below every product.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1u7j9on

***I have added these codes in functions.php to add that button ***

```
//Show Total Sales on Product Page
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wp_product_sold_count', 11 );
function wp_product_sold_count() {
global $product;
$total_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
if ( $total_sold ) echo '
' . sprintf( __( 'Total Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $total_sold ) . '

';
}

//Show Total Sales on Product Loop Pages (Shop, Category, etc.) 

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shop_product_sold_count', 11 );
function shop_product_sold_count() {
global $product;
$total_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
if ( $total_sold) echo '
' . sprintf( __( 'Total Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $total_sold ) . '

';
}


///Stock number showing
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_stock_shop', 10 );
  
function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
   global $product;
   echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );
}
```

Comment: Please refer to the solution already given in stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883290/how-get-i-order-total-count-of-specific-product-in-woocommerce

Comment: **Total sales only increase**, when changing/adjusting the product stock it is not reset to 0 and the **in stock number itself also changes after every order**. An example: Product stock starts at 100, 75 units are sold. Result: total sales = 75 out of 25 on stock and not 75 out of 100. If you adjust the product stock afterwards (product out of stock and then back in stock), the number of total sales would 100+.. in short. Using total sales and the instock value is 
not really an option. You should save these values ​​as separate metadata and take multiple factors into account in the display

Comment: @PHPGeek I HAVE CHECKED THAT ONE, BUT NOT WORKING FOR ME.

Comment: @7uc1f3r thanks for your comment, I know that this is not an option but I need to experiment this, i wanna test this. Kindly help me out

Comment: In very simple words: Need to add a counter below every product item...
(Order number) out of (stock number) & When the order number = stock number ......i will Receive an email for that....so that i can update the stock number.

Comment: @MohitRana SO is primarily intended for programmers with a basic knowledge who get stuck on a problem while trying. 
From your description I can conclude that you would need a (small) custom plugin to meet several points. If you are not able to program this yourself, you better look for someone who can do this for you. In short:  Pure code-writing requests and/or recommendations are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), we expect questions here to relate to [specific programming problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @7uc1f3r I have already approached many developers but they aren't able to do this.